# Combining n-grams

Tags: text-mining

In text mining, if we've computed n-gram counts, for say $n=1\ldots4$, is there a *principled* way to combine them, other than just concatenating the $tf-idf$ matrices for each one? (equivalent to an unweighted sum of kernels if we were to construct kernel matrices for each one). For example, google's n-gram viewer:

http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets

shows that they calculated from unigrams up to 5-grams, but they don't say how they combine them.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you might want to look at [Katz backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katz%27s_back-off_model). This entails training vanilla *n*-gram models for $1 \le n \le N$, then estimating probabilities for large *n* by "backing off" to an (*n*-1)-gram model when the *n*-gram in question was not observed more often than some frequency threshold.

Comment: If possible, please provide a more self-contained answer, e.g., with a brief description of the salient points of what Katz backoff is and why it's relevant. Otherwise, this may be better placed as a comment.

Comment: Interesting ... I'll take a look